# Particular solution of Cauchy equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $x^2y''-2xy'+2y= \log^2x+\log(x^2) $

I tried solving this by substituting:

$x=e^t$

$t=\log x$

$x^2y''=D(D-1)y$

$xy'=Dy$

This transforms to :

$(D^2-3D+2)y=t^2+2t$

The solution is :

$y=y_c+y_p$

$y_c=c_1e^{2t}+c_2e^t$

$y_p=t^2 +2t+2/5$

But I don't get my $y_p$ .How do I evaluate $y_p$?

Comment: You may set $y_p = At^2 +Bt+C$ and use the differential equation to guess the constants $A, B, C$.

Comment: Try this here $$\frac{1}{4} \left(2 \log \left(x^2\right)+2 \log
   ^2(x)+6 \log (x)+13\right)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note** that your $~y_p~$ is $~\dfrac{t^2}{2}+\dfrac{5t}{2}+\dfrac{13}{4}~$ not $~t^2 +2t+2/5~$

**Solution:** $$(D^2-3D+2)y=t^2+2t$$
For particular integral $y_p$,

$y_p=\dfrac{1}{D^2-3D+2}(t^2+2t)$

$~~~=\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\dfrac{1}{1-\frac{3}{2}D+\frac{1}{2}D^2}(t^2+2t)$

$~~~=\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\left(1-\frac{3}{2}D+\frac{1}{2}D^2\right)^{-1}(t^2+2t)$

$~~~=\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\left[1+\left(\frac{3}{2}D-\frac{1}{2}D^2\right)+\left(\frac{3}{2}D-\frac{1}{2}D^2\right)^2+\cdots\right](t^2+2t)$

$~~~=\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\left[(t^2+2t)+\left(\frac{3}{2}(2t+2)-\frac{1}{2}\cdot2\right)+\left(\frac{9}{4}\cdot2\right)\right]$

$~~~=\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\left[t^2+2t+3t+3-1+\frac{9}{2}\right]$

$~~~=\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\left[t^2+5t+\frac{13}{2}\right]$

$~~~=\dfrac{t^2}{2}+\dfrac{5t}{2}+\dfrac{13}{4}$

Comment: What is this method name

Comment: You can find this in `Introductory Course in Differential Equations` by Daniel A. Murray

Comment: You can say this method as "INVERSE OPERATOR METHOD" @Abhinav